# Avoid simultaneously reading multiple files for a dask array

Tags: python, dask

From a library, I get a function that reads a file and returns a numpy array.

I want to build a Dask array with multiple blocks from multiple files.

Each block is the result of calling the function on a file.

When I ask Dask to compute, will Dask asks the functions to read multiple files from the hard disk at the same time?

If that is the case, how to avoid that? My computer doesn't have a parallel file system.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import dask

# Make test data
n = 2
m = 3
x = np.arange(n * m, dtype=np.int).reshape(n, m)
np.save('0.npy', x)
np.save('1.npy', x)

# np.load is a function that reads a file 
# and returns a numpy array.

# Build delayed
y = [dask.delayed(np.load)('%d.npy' % i)
     for i in range(2)]

# Build individual Dask arrays.
# I can get the shape of each numpy array without 
# reading the whole file.
z = [da.from_delayed(a, (n, m), np.int) for a in y]

# Combine the dask arrays
w = da.vstack(z)

print(w.compute())
```

Comment: yup. this is a problem. i test this with 100 files and the hard disk slows to a crawl.

Comment: I will just copy all the numpy arrays to one big hdf5 file without using Dask, and then make a dask array from the hdf5 file. Kind of lucky that I only have to deal with one dask array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an distributed 
[lock](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Lock) primitive - so that your loader function does acquire-read-release.

```
read_lock = distributed.Lock('numpy-read')

@dask.delayed
def load_numpy(lock, fn):
    lock.acquire()
    out = np.load(fn)
    lock.release()
    return out

y = [load_numpy(lock, '%d.npy' % i) for i in range(2)]
```

Also, `da.from_array` accepts a lock, so you could maybe create individual arrays from the delayed function `np.load` directly supplying the lock.

Alternatively, you could assign a single unit of
[resource](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#resources-with-collections) to the worker (with multiple threads), and then compute (or persist) with a requirement of one unit per file-read task, as in the example in the linked doc.

Response to comment: `to_hdf` wasn't specified in the question, I am not sure why it is being questioned now; however, you can use `da.store(compute=False)` with a `h5py.File`, and then specify the resource to use when calling compute. Note that this does *not* materialise the data into memory.

Comment: `da.from_delayed` seems to not have a `lock` keyword. http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.from_delayed

Comment: `da.to_hdf5` can't use resource... http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.to_hdf5  I actually don't use compute because the result is larger than the memory.

Comment: I tried the code you posted. But I guess the treading scheduler does not suport Lock. `AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'execution_state'` ... `ValueError("No workers found")`  I am going to ask a new question.

Comment: I am building a library that creates a tree of transformers. If I use resource, I need to pass the specification of resource between the root to leaf transformer, and make a custom compute method that would consider the specification. That is why I don't like to use resource, unless it has a performance benefit.