# Creating Dask delays with Lock. Error: _thread._local has no execution_state

Tags: python, dask

I want to create a Dask array with multiple blocks.
Each block is from a function that reads a file.
To avoid reading multiple files from the hard disk at the same time, I follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696684/avoid-simultaneously-reading-multiple-files-for-a-dask-array) and use a lock.

But creating the dealays give the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'execution_state'
```

Test:

```
import numpy as np
import dask
import distributed

def make_test_data():
    n = 2
    m = 3
    x = np.arange(n * m, dtype=np.int).reshape(n, m)
    np.save('0.npy', x)
    np.save('1.npy', x)
    shape = (n, m)
    return shape

@dask.delayed
def load_numpy(lock, fn):
    lock.acquire()
    out = np.load(fn)
    lock.release()
    return out

def make_delayed():
    # np.load is a function that reads a file
    # and returns a numpy array.
    read_lock = distributed.Lock('numpy-read')
    return [load_numpy(read_lock, '%d.npy' % i) for i in range(2)]

def main():
    shape = make_test_data()
    ds = make_delayed()

main()
```

Complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<...>/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2536, in get_worker
    return thread_state.execution_state['worker']
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'execution_state'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_lock.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_lock.py", line 30, in main
    ds = make_delayed()
  File "test_lock.py", line 25, in make_delayed
    read_lock = distributed.Lock('numpy-read')
  File "<...>/site-packages/distributed/lock.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.client = client or _get_global_client() or get_worker().client
  File "<...>/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2542, in get_worker
    raise ValueError("No workers found")
ValueError: No workers found
```

Comment: You are right that the lock is appropriate for use with the distributed scheduler, so this is not an error. You can use the distributed scheduler locally too, if you wish.

Comment: After I use a `dask.distributed.Client`, I get another error `can't pickle _thread.lock objects` when I compute one of the delayed. I will open another question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
@dask.delayed
def load_numpy(fn):
    lock = distributed.Lock('numpy-read')
    lock.acquire()
    out = np.load(fn)
    lock.release()
    return out

def make_delayed():
    # np.load is a function that reads a file
    # and returns a numpy array.
    read_lock = distributed.Lock('numpy-read')
    return [load_numpy('%d.npy' % i) for i in range(2)]
```

Comment: But the lock didn't make the i/o significantly faster.

Comment: you now have access to the distributed scheduler's dashboard, which has a profile tab, so you can find out where your time is going. Your question wasn't originally about the performance, but about the locking.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [mdurant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821154/mdurant)'s answer and here is a benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, Lock
import time

@dask.delayed
def locked_load(fn):
    lock = Lock('numpy-read')
    lock.acquire()
    out = np.load(fn)
    lock.release()
    return out


@dask.delayed
def unlocked_load(fn):
    return np.load(fn)


def work(arr_size, n_parts, use_lock=True):
    if use_lock:
        f = locked_load
    else:
        f = unlocked_load
    x = np.arange(arr_size, dtype=np.int)
    for i in range(n_parts):
        np.save('%d.npy' % i, x)
    d = [f('%d.npy' % i) for i in range(n_parts)]
    return dask.compute(*d)


def main():
    client = Client()
    with open("lock_time.txt", "a") as fh:
        n_parts_list = [20, 100]
        arr_size_list = [1_000_000, 5_000_000, 10_000_000]
        for n_part in n_parts_list:
            for arr_size in arr_size_list:
                for use_lock in [True, False]:
                    st = time.time()
                    work(arr_size, n_part, use_lock)
                    en = time.time()
                    fh.write("%d %d %s %s\n" % (
                        n_part, arr_size, use_lock, str(en - st))
                    )
                    fh.flush()
    client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result (computer has 16 GB memory):

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| n_part | arr_size | use_lock |   time   |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|     20 |  1000000 | True     |   0.97   |
|     20 |  1000000 | False    |   0.89   |
|     20 |  5000000 | True     |   7.52   |
|     20 |  5000000 | False    |   6.80   |
|     20 | 10000000 | True     |  16.70   |
|     20 | 10000000 | False    |  15.78   |
|    100 |  1000000 | True     |   3.76   |
|    100 |  1000000 | False    |   6.88   |
|    100 |  5000000 | True     |  43.22   |
|    100 |  5000000 | False    |  38.96   |
|    100 | 10000000 | True     | 291.34   | 
|    100 | 10000000 | False    | 389.34   |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: The benchmark's time also include time for creating the test data. Might fix this later.